# Яндекс API Панорама - Как автоматически установить взгялд в центр здания?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi, яндекс-карта-api

Использую Яндекс JavaScript API 2.1 для получение панорамы на сайт.

По примеру подставляю координаты здания (123308, г.Москва, 3-я Хорошёвская улица, 20),  (55.787644, 37.500477):

```js
ymaps.ready(function () {
    // Для начала проверим, поддерживает ли плеер браузер пользователя.
    if (!ymaps.panorama.isSupported()) {
        // Если нет, то просто ничего не будем делать.
        return;
    }

    // Ищем панораму в переданной точке.
    ymaps.panorama.locate([55.787644, 37.500477]).done(
        function (panoramas) {
            // Убеждаемся, что найдена хотя бы одна панорама.
            if (panoramas.length > 0) {
                // Создаем плеер с одной из полученных панорам.
                var player = new ymaps.panorama.Player(
                        'player1',
                        // Панорамы в ответе отсортированы по расстоянию
                        // от переданной в panorama.locate точки. Выбираем первую,
                        // она будет ближайшей.
                        panoramas[0],
                        // Зададим направление взгляда, отличное от значения
                        // по умолчанию.
                        { direction: [0, 0] }
                    );
            }
        },
        function (error) {
            // Если что-то пошло не так, сообщим об этом пользователю.
            alert(error.message);
        }
    );
```

Получаю панораму на сайте, но направление взгляда в панораме не в нужное здание.
В **direction** можно менять направление, но как это сделать автоматически, чтобы подставляя координаты здания, получать панораму с взглядом на нужное здание?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой возможности нет и не будет. Здания имеют сложную форму и высоту, координаты панорам могут быть близко к зданию или между ними и домом будут препятствия.

В какую точку и на какой высоте вы бы направили камеру тут: https://yandex.ru/maps/-/CCUFbFsQtD ?
А здесь: https://yandex.ru/maps/-/CCUFbFDxoC ?
Почему?

Никакая автоматика не определит, куда вы бы хотели направить взгляд пользователя. И в целом не следует использовать панорамы "просто до кучи". Они тратят в 5 раз больше тарифицируемых запросов. Нужные координаты и угол поворота вы должны задавать специально для заданных вами точек вашей базы объектов.

Comment: А как при этом в самом яндексе при переходе на панораму - взгляд определён на выбранное здание автоматически?

Comment: И к примеру взгляд панорамы изначально не на нужное здание, но маркер адреса в панораме устанолвен правильно. Можно ли навестись на маркер здания?
http://joxi.ru/DrlpMDafV7lyxr.png

Comment: И снова вы не думаете о реальном результате. Даже те панорамы, что включены у зданий, на карте отображают порой бред сивой кобылы, тратя ценнейшие ресурсы - тарифицируемые запросы, трафик и мощности процессора. При том, что результат зачастую жуть жуткая. Для чего пользователю следующие панорамы? https://yandex.ru/maps/-/CCUJQYaxXC https://yandex.ru/maps/-/CCUJQYaZwD Чтобы некомпетентность разработчика вашего финального проекта показать?

Comment: Понимаю, что есть в корне неправильные направления. Но есть же и правильные. Мне интересно как они реализованы

Comment: Как бы это не было реализовано на публичной карте, в API нужных данных всё равно нет. Можно определять координаты выбранной точки панорам для объекта. Затем найти в сети подходящий алгоритм и организовать вычисление азимута из этой точки на координаты объекта. Тогда вы сможете хотя бы повернуть камеру в нужную сторону. Но определить угол наклона к горизонту для хорошего ракурса или вообще целесообразность показа выбранной панорамы (примеры вы видели выше) вам не удастся. Потому трата сил на эту часть проекта не видится разумной.

Comment: Если вы делаете ограниченную базу объектов, например для сервиса торговли недвижимости, лучше сосредоточиться на заполнении для избранных объектов их панорамных точек и лучших параметров в ручном режиме. Или сделать удобный плеер панорам, в котором сможете легко получать угол и координаты, отражающие объект с лучшей стороны, например.

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже возникла необходимость направлять взгляд панорамы в направлении нужной точки. По счастью, объекты можно считать точечными. Вот решение:

```
if (panoramas.length > 0) {
    var pan = panoramas[0];
    var position = pan.getPosition();
    var az = azimuth(position[0], position[1], coordinates[0], coordinates[1]);
    var player = new ymaps.panorama.Player(
        'player1',
        pan,
        {
            direction: [az, 0],
        }
    );
}

...

function azimuth(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
    let a = Math.atan2(y2 - y1, x2 - x1) * 180 / Math.PI;
    if (a < 0) {
        a += 360;
    }
    return a;
}
```